# How Chrome preview encodes/decodes actual response of raw (application/x-pkcs12) type?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, base64, google-chrome-devtools, p12

I'm having an api that returns .p12 file as application/x-pkcs12.

In JS and Network Panel's **response** tab I can see my response like below:

```
0ñhî­:ôOOÜ´bªÒ×aÈÒWÉy®=FvÛmÍ«n0*gOUÀûeÁzd
Éù#%qÎÄ¯gKìïòs6yÁÝëô óÆqV#kÿ{&
Uág¥-hÍÛjÅ×.aÐ¢¡­_+í(pqÞÐº,Gçà¤ýQþÔ§³óåÈ|<Þ9}ml3úï¥Æà@í/«Áö¶z
Tì`AñÚ*®!#à´uFp.³Bd­WüàÓÿ¬^ao§¶<eêþq%.N`{ì]ø
```

But in **Preview** Its showing ASCII like below,

```
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....
```

this I'm able to download because its base64 encoding using 'data:application/x-pkcs12;base64,' + 'data' but I'm not able to reproduce result same as chrome's preview with actual raw response.

I've tried forge js (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) and base64 (https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64) all type of encoding/decoding available UTF8, uriencoding but no luck.

I need to know how chrome works to preview response.

Comment: Javascript strings internally are UCS-2 or UTF-16 so you see the *direct* mapping of the binary data into text, there's no additional [re]encoding.